# How to tag multiple files with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to tag many files with TortoiseSVN. The preferred method of right-drag the files to the tags folder and copy versioned files(see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto.html#tsvn-howto-move) results in an error message when committing:

```
Your working copy apperads to be on a tag path!
You should first switch to a branch or the main trunk before committing.

Do you want to commit anyway?
```

Using the Branch/Tag option for one file in the TortoiseSVN menu will work. But is no option when tagging many files. Also no chance to tag the whole project because these would result in a too complex tags folder.

How to get rid of this errormessage?

Comment: "Tagging" in the SVN context should not be mixed up with "keyword tagging" as it is used e.g. here on StackOverflow. You should only tag an project folder or the whole trunk with for example a version identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get rid of this errormessage?

There is no error message here. This is just a **warning** telling you that the convention is to never modify tags in SVN, for good reasons. Otherwise, what would the distinction between a tag and a branch be? This convention is the only thing separating both concepts.

If you just click "yes", TortoiseSVN will proceed and modify the tag anyway.

> The preferred method of right-drag the files to the tags

Preferred by you perhaps, but this is not the normal way to create tags. Conceptually, a tag is just a name for a particular important revision, so that you refer to it by name instead of by revision number. Therefore, creating a tag should not involve making changes.  You should create tags with the [Branch/Tag menu item](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html#tsvn-dug-branch-1) in the TortoiseSVN context menu, preferably on the root of the trunk or a branch.

Comment: There is no distinction between tag and branch (see [snvbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.tags.html)). It's just a convention. For sure the Branch/Tag menu item should be the right way, but it is time-consuming for our needs. Tagging single files is needed and not tagging dirs. Perhaps we need a new strategy.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have a "tags" folder in to which you are adding/copying files. Check [this link](http://svn.haxx.se/tsvn/archive-2006-06/0101.shtml) for the reason for the message.

In any case, the practice is to tag the entire repository and not specific files/folder. Tagging is cheap. In tortoisesvn, you can use the [branch/tag](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-branchtag.html) option to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you missunterstood me. I'm trying to copy the files to the folder repository/tags form the folder repository/trunk to tag the files. So every file will give me this error. This message is realy annoying and confusing for some people.

Comment: @lueda. Updated answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to have a WC spanning the branch/tags directories, you should only have a checkout of the directory repository/trunk, then use Branch/Tag to branch/tag the files/folders as you need and if in the future you need to access those files make a switch to the branch changing your WC to that branch/tag.

You should think about WC as being a unix symbolic link to the server that you can change via the switch command to the folder you prefer.

If you have the full repository checked out as you branch/tag the updates will me more costly and take more and more space for no reason.